# how to rotate multiple image with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i follow this tutorial http://www.ajaxblender.com/howto-rotate-image-using-javascript-canvas.html , this tutorial work well in only single image. how about multiple image? any ideas?

i have javascript code like this :

```
 var img = null, canvas = null;

$(document).ready(function(){
   //  Initialize image and canvas
   img = document.getElementById('image');
   canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');

   if(!canvas || !canvas.getContext){
       canvas.parentNode.removeChild(canvas);
   } else {
       img.style.position = 'absolute';
       img.style.visibility = 'hidden';
   }
   rotateImage(0);

   //  Handle clicks for control links
   $('#resetImage').click(function(){ rotateImage(0); });
   $('#rotate90').click(function(){ rotateImage(90); });
   $('#rotate180').click(function(){ rotateImage(180); });
   $('#rotate270').click(function(){ rotateImage(270); });
});

function rotateImage(degree)
{
    if(document.getElementById('canvas')){
       var cContext = canvas.getContext('2d');
       var cw = img.width, ch = img.height, cx = 0, cy = 0;

       //   Calculate new canvas size and x/y coorditates for image
       switch(degree){
            case 90:
                cw = img.height;
                ch = img.width;
                cy = img.height * (-1);
                break;
            case 180:
                cx = img.width * (-1);
                cy = img.height * (-1);
                break;
            case 270:
                cw = img.height;
                ch = img.width;
                cx = img.width * (-1);
                break;
       }

        //  Rotate image            
        canvas.setAttribute('width', cw);
        canvas.setAttribute('height', ch);
        cContext.rotate(degree * Math.PI / 180);
        cContext.drawImage(img, cx, cy);
    } else {
        //  Use DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage filter for MSIE
        switch(degree){
            case 0: image.style.filter = 'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=0)'; break;
            case 90: image.style.filter = 'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=1)'; break;
            case 180: image.style.filter = 'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=2)'; break;
            case 270: image.style.filter = 'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3)'; break;
        }
    }
}
```

and my html like this :

```
<div><!-- my html code -->
        <img src="image/a.png" alt="" id="image" />
        <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    </div>
    <p>
        <strong>Rotate Image: </strong>
        <a href="javascript:;" id="resetImage">Reset Image</a>
        <a href="javascript:;" id="rotate90">90&deg;</a>
        <a href="javascript:;" id="rotate180">180&deg;</a>
        <a href="javascript:;" id="rotate270">270&deg;</a>
    </p>
```

this is work well in single image, any idea for run this for multiple image? what should i do?

Comment: That's going to be a bit tricky, but with jQuery you should be able to do it. You'll need to change most of your id's to classes. Setup a canvas for each. You'll have to pass the click event 'e' thru the function(e) and then to the rotateImage(e, degree). You'll then need to get the nearest image to the button, so you know what image to change. Sorry I don't have time to write the code.

Comment: is it possible? when i show image with php, then image id same as file name, how access it in javascript? create array variable for multiple id

Comment: if you can solve this problem, help me please. i'm newbie on javascript